# Integrating a Gaussian Distribution with more than just x in the exponent

Tags: improper-integrals, expected-value, quantum-mechanics, gaussian-integral

So we're given this probability function
$$p(x) = e^{{-a(x-b)}^2}$$
and we have to find the expectation value of $x$ which would be
$$
\left<x\right> 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)^*x p(x) 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{{-2a(x-b)}^2}
$$

The problem for me is when I do integration by parts I need the indefinite integral of $p(x)$ to put into the integration formula. All proofs I've found use trig identities that I'm not sure work with more than just $x^2$ in the exponent. Anyone willing to explain how to find the indefinite integral of $p(x)$?

Comment: You don't need to do integration by parts. The factor $x$ is almost the inner derivative of $e^{-2a(x-b)^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=x-b$:
\begin{align*}
 &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(t+b\right)e^{-2at^2} \; \mathrm{dt}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} te^{-2at^2} \; \mathrm{dt}+b\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2at^2} \; \mathrm{dt} \\
&=b\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2at^2} \; \mathrm{dt} \\
\end{align*}
Where the first integral disappears since it is odd (you can also use a substitution), and the second integral is just the familiar Gaussian distribution (substitue $\xi = t \sqrt{2a}$).

Comment: Could I just plug back in for t and use the solution sqrt(pi/2a)?

Comment: @Afish_58 Yes, but don’t forget the $b$ I pulled out infront of the integral.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense now! thank you!